# why math.ceil return a integer in flask shell command?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, ceil, flask-script

ENV:

```
python: 2.7.5
flask = 0.12.2
flask-cors = 2.0.1
flask-script = 2.0.5
```

start a python shell:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import math
>>> math.ceil(3.2)
4.0
```

the `math.ceil` return a float, but when I use `flask-script` Shell command to start a python shell, it return an integer:

```
$ ./bin/python manage.py shell
==========================================
Starting server at 2018-01-06 15:30:14
==========================================

In [1]: import math

In [2]: math.ceil(3.2)
Out[2]: 4
```

I know `math.ceil` of python3 will return a integer, but i used python2, anyone has good idea?

check python version:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: print (sys.version)
2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]
```

Comment: `./bin/python` starts Python3's shell or Python2.7's ? Please check

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri please look my update, it is python2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause, for our flask app, we add the [future](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/future) package.

> future is the missing compatibility layer between Python 2 and Python 3. It allows you to use a single, clean Python 3.x-compatible codebase to support both Python 2 and Python 3 with minimal overhead.

This package rewrite the `math.ceil` method, it return an integer:

```
In [5]: math.ceil.func_code
Out[5]: <code object ceil at 0x7fd74853cab0, file "/data/apps/ecoboost/eggs/future-0.16.0-py2.7.egg/future/backports/misc.py", line 31>
```

the source code as below:

```
def ceil(x):
    """
    Return the ceiling of x as an int.
    This is the smallest integral value >= x.
    """
    return int(oldceil(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it looks like 4 is an integer. It is possible that flask-script is printing it without the decimal expansion. try running

```
math.ceil(3.2)/3
```

in flask-script. If it is working properly it will print `1.3333333333333333`. If it prints `1` then you should try reinstalling flask-script.